# Html two language option with button (without having to redirect to different page )

Tags: javascript, html, css, web, language-switching

I'm trying to make second language option to the website.
Here are the details for the project :

1) I'm not trying to use Google translator system or any other auto translator service to change the entire website language.

2) I only trying to translate the main description part in the website.

3) I already have written and saved translated version of the description text.

4)I also made a dropdown language option button in a separate file but under same template for both language.

So, to make it clear, my question is :

How can I use language option button to switch the language between 
English and Korean (from English to Korean, and from Korean to English depending on what user select) with the translated description text I have?

----- code below is the dropdown language option button ----------------

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
     <title></title>

     <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
     <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
     <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

     <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </head>

    <body>

    <div class="container">            
       <div class="dropdown">
        <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Language Option
        <span class="caret"></span></button>
        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
          <li><a href="#">English</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Korean</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You can use i18 if you are planning to use any javascript framework if you want to do in plain HTML you can serve two different static files with content changed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is how i do it when i build a multi-lingual website. I put notes inside the code for clarification.

```
<form>
    <label for="lang-switch">
        <span lang="ko">언어</span>
        <span lang="en">Language</span>
    </label>
    <select id="lang-switch">
        <option value="en">English</option>
        <option value="ko" selected>한국어</option>
    </select>
</form>

<p>
    <span lang="ko">한국어 텍스트</span>
    <span lang="en">Text in English</span>
</p>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js" integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
$('[lang]').hide(); // hide all lang attributes on start.
$('[lang="ko"]').show(); // show just Korean text (you can change it)
$('#lang-switch').change(function () { // put onchange event when user select option from select
    var lang = $(this).val(); // decide which language to display using switch case. The rest is obvious (i think)
    switch (lang) {
        case 'en':
            $('[lang]').hide();
            $('[lang="en"]').show();
        break;
        case 'ko':
            $('[lang]').hide();
            $('[lang="ko"]').show();
        break;
        default:
            $('[lang]').hide();
            $('[lang="ko"]').show();
        }
});
</script>
```

Hope it solve your problem.

(since i don't speak Korean i used google-translate for the example)

Answer (score 1):

Javascript is your best bet. In your `<li>` tags, you want to add an `onclick` event listener so that you can change the text of an HTML element when you select a list item.

```
<li onclick="toggleLanguage('English')"><a href="#">English</a></li>
<li onclick="toggleLanguage('English')"><a href="#">Korean</a></li>
```

Here, the `onclick` attribute calls the function: `function toggleLanguage(language)`.

Next, create a `<script>` tag after the body to call your javascript code.

```
<script>
    function toggleDescriptor(language) {
        let description = document.getElementById("description");
        if (language === "Korean") {
            description.innerHTML = "Show Korean Text";
        }
        else {
            description.innerHTML = "Show English Text";
        }  
    }
<script>
```

This function accesses the element that you want to change the text to. In this case, I created an `h1` tag with an `id="description"`.

Here is an example of the all the changes:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

<div class="container">
  <h1 id="description">Show English Text</h1>
   <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Language Option
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
      <li onclick="toggleLanguage('English')"><a href="#">English</a></li>
      <li onclick="toggleLanguage('Korean')"><a href="#">Korean</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
<script>
  function toggleLanguage(language) {
    let description = document.getElementById("description");
    if (language === "Korean") {
      description.innerHTML = "Show Korean Text";
    }
    else {
      description.innerHTML = "Show English Text";
    }
  }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you! I tried this solution and it worked! But I have another question to ask you, what if  I have several paragraphs to translate  in my index.html file, then do I need to use if and else multiple times? So I'm translating FAQ section and that has 4 questions total. And I want the language option button to work for the entire FAQ section. Right now, I just tried with one of the questions and answer with the solution that you provided, but I wasn't sure if there's any way I can do without having to have 5-6 more if and else statement. Hope my question make sense to you, Thank you :)

Comment: No problem. If you want to translate more than one element, you would just get the DOM element using `document.getElementById("<id here>")` then in the if statement, you would simply set each DOM element to the respective language texts. There wouldn't be more if/else statements since the if/else is used to differentiate between Korean and English. Instead, you'll just have more lines under each if statement.

Comment: If there is a lot of text to translate, you could consider putting the respective texts in a different file (JSON) and use XMLHttp (AJAX) to load the text dynamically.