# How to do that by clicking on the language selection icon, a list of available languages drops out?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How to do that by clicking on the language selection icon, a list of available languages ​​(UA, EN, IT) drops out. When you click on one of them, the list of languages ​​is hidden and the selected one appears in this icon?

```css
    header .leftSide,
    header .rightSide
    {
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="language">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="LANG" href="#">RU</a></li>
      <li><a id="LANG" href="#">ENG</a></li>
      <li><a id="LANG" href="#">IT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yiByi.png)

Comment: `by clicking on the language selection icon` what do you mean? What to click?

Comment: @לבנימלכה To drop out the list of languages, and apply the selected

Comment: Do not set same ID to all `a` ID is unique to each element

Comment: @לבנימלכה Ok) But how to make a drop-down list?)
But not in the usual ul> li

Comment: do you mean select:https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_select.asp

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_dropdown_button

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Html two language option with button (without having to redirect to different page )](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021813/html-two-language-option-with-button-without-having-to-redirect-to-different-pa)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`.click()`](https://api.jquery.com/click/) `a` and in function [`hide()`](https://api.jquery.com/hide) list and style `li` as below:

```js
$('.a-tag').click(function() {
  $('.language').hide();
});
```

```css
li{
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 1px solid black;
    padding: 5px;
    margin: 5px;
    width: fit-content;
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="language">
    <ul>
      <li><a id="LANG1" class="a-tag" href="#">RU</a></li>
      <li><a id="LANG2" class="a-tag" href="#">ENG</a></li>
      <li><a id="LANG3" class="a-tag" href="#">IT</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: that what you mean?