# staying on the current page when changing language

Tags: php

I'm setting up a language switcher for my website but have an issue with the actual switcher which always brings back to the homepage (index.php).  :-s very annoying

I a complete newbie in php and have been following this tutorial to do so on youtube: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cgvDMUrQ3vA

I am trying to implement it on a multi pages website. The actual language swap works like a charm and seems to keep the set language throughout the pages but the mechanism for the switch doesn't because it uses a static link to load index.php + new language attribute, bringing the visiter inevitably back to the homepage instead of reloading the current page.

```
<?php echo $lang['lang-selector-href']  /* set the <a> tag src="index+lang='x'" */ ?>
<?php echo $lang['lang-selector-switch'] /* display language to be set */  ?>
</a>
```

i'm using 2 similar files (en.php and fr.php) containing an array to store the translated content

en.php  :

```
<?php
$lang = array(
   "lang-selector-href" => "<a href='index.php?lang=fr'>",
   "lang-selector-switch" => "Français (French)",
...
...

);
?>
```

fr.php  :

```
<?php
$lang = array(
  "lang-selector-href" => "<a href='index.php?lang=en'>",
  "lang-selector-switch" => "English (anglais)",
...
...

);
?>
```

**Question: 
How could i could I change the link to:**

```
<a href='current-page.php?lang=fr'> Français (French) </a>
```

**or:**

```
<a href='current-page.php?lang=en'> English </a>
```

**according to the set language?**

here is my config.php file

```
<?php
session_start();

// if no language selected go for english
if (!isset($_SESSION['lang']))
    $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";


else if (isset($_GET['lang']) && $_SESSION['lang'] != $_GET['lang'] && !empty($_GET['lang'])) {
    if ($_GET['lang'] == "en")
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "en";
    else if ($_GET['lang'] == "fr")
        $_SESSION['lang'] = "fr";
}

// load content
require_once "content/languages/" . $_SESSION['lang'] . ".php";

?>
```

Sorry if it sounds very basic, i'm sure it is but couldn't find a simple answer that would work...
Thank you!

Comment: You could just remove `index.php` from those links leaving you with `"<a href='?lang=fr'>"` etc. (Note: this will also remove any other GET parameter for this URL though)

Comment: Maybe try a js solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53021813/html-two-language-option-with-button-without-having-to-redirect-to-different-pa/53025034#53025034

Comment: @kerbholz it actually works ! And while i'm not using any other GET parameter for this URL it's dent seem to be an issue here. So easy! thanks you

Comment: No problem, glad it works

Answer (score 0):

Make Dropdown list in html which options have language value like below as,

```
    <select onchange="callSomeFunc()">
       <option value="fr">French</option>
       <option value="en">English</option>
    </select>
```

On change of dropdown list you need to call function which will set selected language value in to php `$_SESSION.`

Comment: Without the code for `callSomeFunc()` this does in no way solve or help with OPs problem.